# Is there an alternative to using the REST API for my Android app?

Tags: android, rest, cloud, google-drive-android-api

I have been struggling for many weeks to get the sample code at [REST Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) to work properly, but I get a 403 error which I can't seem to fix as I cannot find the Drive SDK within the Developer Console to activate it for my app.

Now I am wondering if there is an alternative to using the REST method to achieve my original goal of creating an app that can create and edit text files within a users personal Google Drive account - NOT the Drive space allocated to the app itself - which I believe is a limitation of the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro#audience) (unless I'm mistaken)?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The Google Drive Android API is NOT limited to the app space like you suggest. The limitation is in the drive scopes (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes) available to your app.
You will not be able to get the "drive" scope.
But from what you describe you can get by with drive.file scope.

Comment: @Anatoli - thank you, I will look into your suggestion.